# How to use 2D arrays with other classes

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment, I was wondering how I could go about using 2D arrays with another class, I have a class called `Die` that looks like this:

```
public class Die
{
   private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value

   private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

   public Die()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }


   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }


   public void setFaceValue(int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }


   public int getFaceValue()
   {
     return faceValue;
   }


   public String toString()
   {
      String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

      return result;
   }
}
```

Now in a main method i have to do the following

[image]

I have all the other parts done, I just cant seem to figure out this part.

My current code(Not started this part) is below

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ASgn8 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many players? ");
    int playerCount = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    String[] playerNames = new String[playerCount];
    int again = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("What is your name: ");
        playerNames[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    int randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * (30-10)) +10;


    }   
 }
```

Do any of you java geniuses have any advice for me to begin?

Thanks!

Comment: is it necessary to use only 2-D array, can't we use Any Collection classes ?

Comment: A 2D array of dice can be created with `Die[][] diceArray = new Die[][]` ... Is that your question?

Comment: @vishalgajera  -- yes it has to be a 2-D Array!

Comment: @BenKnoble -- My question is basically, how to get the values to store in the right spot, Like aslong as the player wants to play, which is always 5 or  less, And if that person's turn is done, i want it to change to the other player which would switch to the second row and restart the process.

Comment: So, what you need is two loops. One on the inside for each player that will roll the dice and ask if they want to keep playing. It will be responsible for keeping track of which spot of the 5 the dice goes in. When theyre done playing, move to the next player. Thus, the outer loop is responsible for which players turn it is. Your indices for the array become [player#][dice#]. Does this make sense?

Comment: @BenKnoble- So the inside loop should be a while loop and not a for loop correct? So it can ask if the player wants to keep playing? and the array would look like myDie[j][i] = roll; where j increments only when the first user doesn't want to play again? and i increments after iteration? Is that kind of what you meant?

Comment: @JonRoy kindly see my EDITED part which is actually your choice answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your main method, you just need to update your main method with this one,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("How many players? ");
            int playerCount = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();

            HashMap<String, ArrayList<Die>> hashMap = new  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Die>>();
            int again = 1;

            for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("What is your name: ");
                hashMap.put(scan.nextLine(),new ArrayList<Die>());
            }

            for(String key : hashMap.keySet()){
                System.out.println(key + "'s turn....");
                Die d = new Die();
                System.out.println("Rolled : " + d.roll()) ;
                hashMap.get(key).add(d);
                System.out.println("Want More (Yes/No) ???");
                String choice = scan.next();
                while(choice != null && choice.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
                    if(hashMap.get(key).size()>4){System.out.println("Sorry, Maximum 5-Try you can...!!!");break;}
                    Die dd = new Die();
                    System.out.println("Rolled : " + dd.roll()) ;
                    hashMap.get(key).add(dd);
                    System.out.println("Want More (Yes/No) ???");
                    choice = scan.next();
                }
            }

            for(String key : hashMap.keySet()){
                System.out.println(key + " - " + hashMap.get(key));
            }


        }
```

**EDITED**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("How many players? ");
            int playerCount = scan.nextInt(); // get number of participant player...
            scan.nextLine();

            Die[] tempDie = new Die[5]; // temporary purpose
            Die[][] finalDie = new Die[5][]; // final array in which all rolled dies stores...

            String [] playerName = new String[playerCount]; // stores player name

            int totalRollDie = 0; // keep track number of user hash rolled dies...

            for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) // get all player name from command prompt...
            {
                System.out.print("What is your name: ");
                String plyrName = scan.nextLine();
                playerName[i] = plyrName;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++){ 

                System.out.println(playerName[i] + "'s turn....");
                    totalRollDie = 0;
                    Die d = new Die();
                    System.out.println("Rolled : " + d.roll()) ;
                    tempDie[totalRollDie] = d; 
                    totalRollDie++;
                    System.out.println("Want More (Yes/No) ???");
                    String choice = scan.next();

                        while(choice != null && choice.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
                            if(totalRollDie < 5){ // if user want one more time to roll die then first check whether alread user has rolled 5-time or not.
                            Die dd = new Die();
                            System.out.println("Rolled : " + dd.roll()) ; // rolled and print whatever value get..
                            tempDie[totalRollDie] = dd;
                            totalRollDie++;
                            System.out.println("Want More (Yes/No) ???");
                            choice = scan.next();
                        }
                    }

                    finalDie[i] = new Die[totalRollDie];
                    for(int var = 0 ; var < totalRollDie ; var++){
                        finalDie[i][var] = tempDie[var]; // store Die object into finalDie array which can random number for all user.. 
                    }
            }

            for(int i = 0 ;i < playerCount ; i++){ // finally print whatever user's roll value with all try...
                System.out.println(" --------- " + playerName[i] + " ------------ ");
                for(Die de : finalDie[i]){
                    System.out.println(de);
                }
            }

            tempDie = null;

        }
```

Comment: Unfortunatley, we are not allowed to use ArrayList and hashMap etc.

Comment: Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: hey dude, the code stops after one turn, any way to fix that, the code looks good tho, thanks.